# CommandBinding in ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, hierarchicaldatatemplate, commandbinding

I have a TreeView and have created a basic TreeItem type. Each TreeItem has a header, a TreeItem Collection for children and a collection for a possible context menu. The TreeItem class has those objects:

```
public delegate void dExecute(TreeItem item);

public dExecute ExecuteTarget { get; set; }
public object Tag { get; set; }
public string Header { get; set; }
public List<TreeItem> Children { get; set; }
public List<TreeItem> ContextMenu { get; set; }
```

The context menu uses again a HierarchicalDataTemplate to display TreeItem objects (I use the TreeItem class for the items in the treeview AND in the context menu). The context menu looks like this:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Visibility="{Binding ShowContextMenu}" ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenu}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"  />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Execute}"/>
                </Style>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

The context menu is rendered as I want it to be. I have created a context menu that I just attach to some of my items in the tree view. This is its content.

```
public List<TreeItem> ContextMenu
{
    get
    {
        List<TreeItem> list = new List<TreeItem>();
        TreeItem ti = new TreeItem("Some Action") { ExecuteTarget = targetMethod};
        list.Add(ti);
        ti = new TreeItem("test");
        ti.Children.Add(new TreeItem("foo") { ExecuteTarget = targetMethod});
        ti.Children.Add(new TreeItem("bar") { ExecuteTarget = targetMethod});
        ti.Children.Add(new TreeItem("foo") { ExecuteTarget = targetMethod});
        TreeItem ti2 = new TreeItem("inner"){ ExecuteTarget = targetMethod};
        ti.Children.Add(ti2);
        ti2.Children.Add(new TreeItem("foo") { ExecuteTarget = targetMethod});
        list.Add(ti);
        return list;
    }
}
```

The context menu looks like this.

[image: The rendered context menu]

It looks as it should be. The commands work as they should. EXCEPT for the command on the highest level of the context menu. When I click on "Some Action" nothing happens. I assume that I have to add something to XAML, but I have no idea where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Visibility="{Binding ShowContextMenu}" ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenu}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"  />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Execute}"/>
                </Style>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>

    <!-- this is what you're missing -->
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Execute}"/>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: I could kiss you right now! You have no idea for how long I had a really stupid look on my face, while trying to figure that out. Thanks heaps!!